# Rounded corners of a grid in Silverlight

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, rounded-corners

I'm trying to set the rounded corners of my grid. The cells inside the grid
have set their own background color values. Because of that, when I specify
the border around the grid to have rounded corners, I get an awful result -
the grid is NOT clipped to fit the border.

So as to that, the corners of my grid go outside the border.

What is the solution for that problem?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708393/how-to-set-the-rounded-inside-corners-of-a-grid-in-silverlight-4

Comment: Are you referring to Grid, the layout Panel, or DataGrid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should instead use a border and place the grid inside it. Set the grid background transparent and then set the color on the border. The border can have rounded edges so then the background will be clipped to those rounded edges.

Comment: Yup, but what if I want one column of my grid to have a different color than the other one? And if I want to display the borders of the cells?